# multiple iteration is done for creating the generic filters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, code-reuse

I am trying to develop a generic filter component which can have many fields to filter on like color,
size, price range etc and each field might have different types of elements like color may have
checkboxes, radio button and price range might have input element, dropdown etc. To support such varied
cases, I tried to go with this pattern but here I have to iterate the same things multiple times.

I am not sure of this data structure. If anyone has suggestion please help me to improve this code but
the main problem here is "multiple iteration". How can i improve this code?

```
const filterParams = {
  field: {
    id     : 1, label  : 'Field', content: <FieldFilter />
  },
  employee: {
    id     : 1, label  : 'Employee', content: <Employee />
  }
}

<Filter filterParams={filterParams} activeFilterParam="field" />
```

```
const Filter = ({ filterParams, activeFilterParam }) => {
  const [show, setShow]=useState(false)
  return (
    <>
      <Button secondary icon={filter} onClick={() => setShow(!show)}>Filter</Button>
      {show && (
        <Card style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>
          <Card.Content>
            <Tabs activeTab={activeFilterParam}>
              <Tabs.List
                render={() => {
                  return (
                    Object.keys(filterParams).map(filterParam => {
                      return (
                        <Tabs.Tab key={filterParam} id={filterParam}>{filterParams[filterParam].label}</Tabs.Tab>
                      )
                    }))
                }} />
              <Tabs.Panels>
                {Object.keys(filterParams).map(filterParam => {
                  return (
                    <Tabs.Panel key={filterParam} panelId={filterParam}>{filterParams[filterParam].content}</Tabs.Panel>
                  )
                })}
              </Tabs.Panels>
            </Tabs>
          </Card.Content>
          <Card.Footer>
            <Button>
              <Button.Content style={{ marginRight: 10 }}>Save</Button.Content>
              <Button.Content secondary onClick={()=>setShow(!show)}>Cancel</Button.Content>
            </Button>
          </Card.Footer>
        </Card>
      )}
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: It's a little ugly, but I don't really see anything wrong with it.

Comment: can you point the ugly part, please? if you have any suggestion on where I can improve, please suggest me.

Comment: Is the "multiple iteration" you refer to the component mapping?  I agree with @FrankerZ.  I think perhaps using memoization may help if you're seeing performance issues re-rendering these filters if you have a ton of them.  Wrap the export of `Filter` component in react's memo HOC and pass a custom propsEqual function, or factor out and use the `useMemo` hook to compute the `Tabs.Tab` and `Tabs.Panel` components arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not liking the multiple calls to `Object.keys(filterParams).map`, you could move the loop to the top of the component function.  Something like the below might work:

```
const Filter = ({ filterParams, activeFilterParam }) => {
  const [show, setShow]=useState(false)

  const {tabs, panels} = Object.keys(filterParams)
    .reduce((acc, filterParam) => {
      acc.tabs.push(
        <Tabs.Tab key={filterParam} id={filterParam}>{filterParams[filterParam].label}</Tabs.Tab>
      );
      acc.panels.push(
        <Tabs.Panel key={filterParam} panelId={filterParam}>{filterParams[filterParam].content}</Tabs.Panel>
      );
      return acc;
    }, { tabs: [], panels: [] });

  return (
    ...
        <Card style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>
          <Card.Content>
            <Tabs activeTab={activeFilterParam}>
              <Tabs.List render={() => tabs} />
              <Tabs.Panels>
                {panels}
              </Tabs.Panels>
            </Tabs>
            ...
        </Card>
    ...
  )
}
```

Note that I haven't run this - it likely won't be quite right, but should give the general idea...

Comment: A step further would be to use `useMemo` to additionally memoize the results so if the `filterParams` prop value doesn't update then the last computed value is returned.

Comment: useMemo for Filter component?

Comment: @Serenity You could use [`React.memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) for the entire `Filter` component, and/or [the `useMemo` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) to memoize just the object returned by the `reduce` call. Which is appropriate depends on how likely (and which of) the props passed to the `Filter` component are to change.

Comment: sure I will play with memo. Thanks a lot everyone.